# How to go to a file in a solution when the file path doesnt match the solution path

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, file-management

I'm working on a massive solution, thousands of source files, hundreds of projects and a solution folder structure that doesn't match the folder structure on windows.

If for example I use the "Find All References" feature of visual studio and open up a source file from the results I cant find an easy way to go to this file in the solution explorer and see what project it belongs to.

I'm aware of the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option in "Projects and Solutions-> General" but i hate this. It essentially ends up with all the folders in my solution expanded which is annoying. Is there a way to do a similar thing but "on demand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Search Solution Explorer feature. (Shortcut - Ctrl + ;)

In the solution explorer exists a field where you could type the filename you are looking for. All files & functions having the same name are displayed in a hierarchial order. The results displayed would easily help you to ascertain the project the file belongs to, unless you have multiple projects with same filename.

Comment: Perfect. Didnt know about the Ctrl + ; and i never noticed that search bar at the top of the solution explorer. haha

Comment: There are umpteen other things that we would still not have noticed! Happy coding.